# Is it possible to decrypt a password without having to use compare? (bcrypt)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, jwt, bcrypt

I'm implementing a "forgot password" system in my authentication API in node. For this I created a "forgetPassword" controller where I send the user's email through req.body and with that an email with the recovery token is sent to the user, and that same token is also sent inside of the model user in the database in "tokenReset". The second controller is "resetPassword", where this recovery token is sent by params and a new password is sent in the req.body.

The biggest problem is, I think it's not safe for this token to be in the database without being encrypted, as someone inside the database can take advantage of this as a flaw, so I encrypted the token before sending it to the database. But the big question is, I have to fetch this token inside the database in "resetPassword" controller through the token sent in the params, but the token inside my database is encrypted and the one in the params is not. What would be the best way to resolve this?

forgotPassword controller

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const db = require('../../models/index');
const sendEmail = require('../../utils/mailer');

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

exports.store = async (req, res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;
    const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;

    try {

        const user = await db.User.findOne({ where: { email } });
 
        if (!user) {
            res.status(400).json('User does not exist.');
        }


        const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, secret, {
            expiresIn: process.env.EXPIRES_FORGOTPASS,
        });

        const hashedToken = bcrypt.hashSync(token, 10);

        await user.update({
            tokenReset: hashedToken,
        });

        sendEmail({
            from: 'noreply@email.com',
            to: 'admin@gmail.com',
            subject: 'Reset your password',
            text: `Token sending email to reset password account from ${user.email}`,
            html: `<h2>Token sending email to reset password account from ${user.email}</h2>
                    <h4>${token}</h4>
            `,    
        });

        return res.status(200).json('Check the verification link in your email!');
    } catch (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
}
```

resetPassword controller

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const db = require('../../models/index');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const sendEmail = require('../../utils/mailer');

exports.store = async (req, res) => {
    const { token } = req.params;
    const { password } = req.body;
    const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;

    try {

        const userExists = await db.User.findOne({ where: { tokenReset: token } });

        if (!userExists) {
            return res.status(401).json('User not found in our database!');
        }

        try {
            await jwt.verify(token, secret);
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(401).json('Link expired, make a new password reset request!');
        }

        const hashedNewPass = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);

        await userExists.update({
            password: hashedNewPass,
            tokenReset: "",
        });

        return res.status(200).json(`Password updated!`);
    } catch (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot decrypt a hashed password; that's pretty much **the whole point** of using a secure hash.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I could make this password recovery system?

Comment: Actually sending the token into the database without encrypting it would be insecure, right?

Comment: You can email the token out in its original form (random string of characters), and then check it against the database just like you'd check a password: hash the incoming token and see if it matches. Note that part of the recovery link has to identify the user, like a database key or something.

Comment: When the user submits the password reset token you sent them, hash it and compare the hashed value to what’s in the database.

Comment: So the token sent to the params must be encrypted as well? Because there's no way I can pull the user from the database with a normal token and the token being encrypted inside the database

Comment: Some kind of database key has to be part of the token link you send. If you're storing the tokens in their own table, then the unique key for the token row is fine, and the row should contain the id of the user it relates to.